# push method in Array not working - Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angularjs, api, angular, promise

I am stuck with this piece of code for last 4 hours, unable to figure out what's the issue. It's written in typescript.
the **newsa** array is to be filled with the data I've pulled using the api. but instead, it shows errors like **can't find push property**, after I declare the array properly with all needs like the public prefix and all. There is no error but nothing is getting pushed. What's wrong. 
It would be great help if you answer.

```
public newsa: Array<any> = [];
fetchNews() {
    console.log("Fetch NEws has started");
    var that = this;
    let googlenewsUrl:string;
    let finalUrl: string;

    this.countries.forEach(function(i) {

        googlenewsUrl = "https://news.google.com/news?q=" + i.name.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "&output=rss";
        finalUrl = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(googlenewsUrl);
        that.jsonp.get(finalUrl).toPromise().then(news => that.newsa.push(news)).catch(that.handleError);           
    });

}
```

Comment: also the api request is a successful one. everything working perfectly except the main pushing part.

Comment: You should then answer you own question with your solution. [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: @HrishikeshBarman If you've figured it out you must add your answer below, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 function(i)
```

use

```
 (i) =>
```

to retain the scope of `this`